# Vaadin pie chart label formatter not working

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-charts

I have a chart in Vaadin 8 with the following formatter for y axis labels:

```
chart.getConfiguration().getyAxis().getLabels()
    .setFormatter("function() { return this.point.name + ' sample'; }");
```

I can't seem to get it to work correctly, as the chart always displays *only* the `point.name` part and not the `' sample'` part. I did the same for the tooltip where it works:

```
chart.getConfiguration().getTooltip()
        .setFormatter("function() { return this.point.name + ' sample'; }");
```

Screenshot for confirmation:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After quite some time I found the answer, I had to set the label formatting function in the `PlotOptionsPie` object:

```
PlotOptionsPie plot = new PlotOptionsPie();
plot.setInnerSize("60%");  // hollow inside -> "donut" chart
plot.getDataLabels().setFormatter("function() { return this.point.name + ' sample'; }");
chart.getConfiguration().setPlotOptions(plot);
```

The result:

[image]